# zsh in tabby separate history for each tab

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I want to keep history separated for each tab (even for split windows within one tab). I therefore found a solution to add these two lines after `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`:

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
unsetopt inc_append_history
unsetopt share_history
```

Now the history is really separated, nevertheless when I completely close the terminal (in my case Tabby), the histories for each tab are common again. How to solve that?
I use `zsh` with `Tabby`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your tabs’ histories separate even after a restart, then you will need to declare a different `$HISTFILE` in each tab, because (as mentioned [in the documentation of the `fc` command](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-fc)):

> `$HISTFILE` is considered local when read at startup.

Comment: Can u tel me exactly where to define such change?

Comment: i tried like this but doesnt work:
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
setopt noincappendhistory
unsetopt nosharehistory
unsetopt appendhistory

Comment: Like I said, you need to set the `$HISTFILE` parameter.

Comment: how exactly, can u put as an asnwer?

Comment: For this to work, you will need to have a unique ID that persists between restarts for each tab. Does tabby have an environment variable you can use for this? I don’t use Tabby myself.